# Firebase: react-native: get instance id, iid from '@react-native-firebase/iid' not working

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

My code to used to work. It did:

```
import iid from '@react-native-firebase/iid';
...
  tokenDevice = await iid().getToken();
```

But now, I get

> TypeError: (0, _iid.default) is not a function. (In '(0, _iid.default)()', '(0, _iid.default)' is undefined)

It seems my code cannot import '@react-native-firebase/iid' anymore.
Besides, other firebase packages have versions 12+, package iid is stuck at 11.5, and react-native firebase documentation does not reference iid anymore
https://rnfb-docs.netlify.app/reference

What can I do to get my device token to send messages to a particular phone ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iid module was deprecated. The right code to get the token is

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging'
const deviceToken = await messaging().getToken()
```